# Parse.com UIRemoteNotificationType Deprecated

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Following the Parse.com tutorial for push notifications, I put this Swift code into my application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
        // Register for Push Notitications
    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.
        
        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }
```

I'm getting these two warnings:

> 'UIRemoteNotificationType' was deprecated in iOS version 8.0: Use UIUserNotificationType for user notifications and registerForRemoteNotifications for receiving remote notifications instead.
>
> 'registerForRemoteNotificationsTypes' was deprecated in iOS version 8.0: Please use registerForRemoteNotifications and registerUserNotificationSettings: instead

Can I simply just swap out what it's telling me to?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is pretty black and white. Yes you can simply swap it out, with one caveat:

If you are targeting devices with iOS 7, then no you need that. However, if you are developing for iOS7...my opinion, stop it. As of Aug 31 and [According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/) there isn't that many users who still have this OS on their device, and that data isn't even including the public iOS 9s, so your wasting a lot of your time on an OS no one uses. However if you *really* have to support iOS 7 you need to include all of that in addition to the non-deprecated versions. Otherwise, you can just swap it out as you stated with the non-deprecated versions.

Here's a Swift 2.0 example :

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
   let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
   let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)
   application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
   application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
} else {
   let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
   application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't need to target iOS 7.  So I swapped those last few lines out with: `} else {
            let types = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications(types)
        }`  but I get the error: Cannot invoke registerForRemoteNotifications with an argument list of type UIUserNotificationType

Comment: I don't get it. for your iOS8 version you are doing: `registerForRemoteNotifications()` but you aren't passing any type. How does it know what types it must register?